Dual Boot two UEFI enabled Linux distirbutions (Kali / Fedora) with grub
I am trying to install two Linux systems on one NVMe drive and have them listed in GRUB.
Initial Steps

I initially installed Kali Linux first and sized the partitions, so that half of the NVMe (250 GB) was allocated for Kali.

Then I ran the installation routine for Fedora and allocated the second half of the NVMe. Both installation where initiated from USB thumb drives.

After rebooting, Fedora was the "default" Linux distro to start.

When I hit F9 to bring up the UEFI boot menu of my laptop, it displays the following options:

UEFI - Fedora
UEFI - Kali

So it seems like UEFI has found both instalaltions.

Executing update-grubon Kali produced the following output:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/kali/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.11-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.11-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.6.15-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.6.15-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Fedora 32 (Workstation Edition) on /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done


However, the when selecting Fedora 32... from the grub boot menu, it won't start. Some components fail during startup.


General UEFI Boot

I can start Kali by selecting UEFI - Kali from the boot menu (F9).
Likewise I can start Fedora by selecting UEFI - Fedora from the boot menu (F9).

Fedora Information
Here is the output of lsblk -f when UEFI - Fedora has been booted:
NAME                            FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                                                                                                          
├─nvme0n1p1                     vfat        FAT32          8EBB-B5AA                                             
├─nvme0n1p2                     ext2        1.0            99c384de-2956-474c-9a6f-26c517582ceb                  
├─nvme0n1p3                     LVM2_member LVM2 001       puD1Th-hG9t-MZ2V-5mnE-PaEF-idOa-GoQRKy                
│ ├─kalii--vg-swap_1            swap        1              2c22ebce-039f-4f45-960f-b3ee79cb636c                  
│ ├─kalii--vg-root              ext4        1.0            f314b58a-0d30-43b0-9845-d9c653347d76                  
│ ├─kalii--vg-var               ext4        1.0            309b5290-4f13-4aac-a6ea-503146224728                  
│ ├─kalii--vg-tmp               ext4        1.0            d9963dfe-4ac0-4eaa-b1e8-3b38452a6b23                  
│ └─kalii--vg-home              ext4        1.0            2b354662-c5dd-45cb-a4f6-8670b1dab590                  
├─nvme0n1p4                     vfat        FAT16          0FC2-F7FE                               479.3M     4% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p5                     ext4        1.0            e81a47a9-930f-4941-9403-fd46312781cc    244.9M    42% /boot
└─nvme0n1p6                     LVM2_member LVM2 001       3dYM1x-ldPJ-AWtd-1w6Y-r8J0-bv7U-WeEyQ9                
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-root ext4        1.0            3566e840-5d28-43d7-b40f-bc2afb27e1bd     17.7G    22% /
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-swap swap        1              76c891c4-7866-4536-a40a-0912d1ebd5f8                  [SWAP]
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-tmp  ext4        1.0            5666f4b7-a4ba-4931-b219-407bc42eedd6      7.4G     0% /tmp
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-home ext4        1.0            6a99e0ff-a3f3-4a49-b9cb-dcabdc951784      139G     0% /home
  └─fedora_localhost--live-var  ext4        1.0            a20aa6a5-2b6e-47fc-aecd-c7e25a388113      3.5G    59% /var

The filtered tree for /boot on the Fedora installation looks like this:
root@localhost john]# tree -P *efi* -P *grub* /boot
/boot
├── efi
│   ├── EFI
│   │   ├── BOOT
│   │   └── fedora
│   │       ├── fonts
│   │       ├── grub.cfg
│   │       ├── grubenv
│   │       ├── grubia32.efi
│   │       └── grubx64.efi
│   └── System
│       └── Library
│           └── CoreServices
├── extlinux
├── grub2
│   ├── grubenv -> ../efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv
│   └── themes
│       └── system
├── loader
│   └── entries
└── lost+found


Kali Information
Here is the output of lsblk -f when UEFI - Kali has been booted:
NAME                            FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1                                                                                                          
├─nvme0n1p1                     vfat        FAT32          8EBB-B5AA                               508.1M     1% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                     ext2        1.0            99c384de-2956-474c-9a6f-26c517582ceb    231.3M    44% /boot
├─nvme0n1p3                     LVM2_member LVM2 001       puD1Th-hG9t-MZ2V-5mnE-PaEF-idOa-GoQRKy                
│ ├─kalii--vg-root              ext4        1.0            f314b58a-0d30-43b0-9845-d9c653347d76      8.2G    59% /
│ ├─kalii--vg-var               ext4        1.0            309b5290-4f13-4aac-a6ea-503146224728      6.7G    21% /var
│ ├─kalii--vg-swap_1            swap        1              2c22ebce-039f-4f45-960f-b3ee79cb636c                  [SWAP]
│ ├─kalii--vg-tmp               ext4        1.0            d9963dfe-4ac0-4eaa-b1e8-3b38452a6b23      1.7G     0% /tmp
│ └─kalii--vg-home              ext4        1.0            2b354662-c5dd-45cb-a4f6-8670b1dab590    139.7G     0% /home
├─nvme0n1p4                     vfat        FAT16          0FC2-F7FE                                             
├─nvme0n1p5                     ext4        1.0            e81a47a9-930f-4941-9403-fd46312781cc                  
└─nvme0n1p6                     LVM2_member LVM2 001       3dYM1x-ldPJ-AWtd-1w6Y-r8J0-bv7U-WeEyQ9                
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-tmp  ext4        1.0            5666f4b7-a4ba-4931-b219-407bc42eedd6                  
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-swap swap        1              76c891c4-7866-4536-a40a-0912d1ebd5f8                  
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-root ext4        1.0            3566e840-5d28-43d7-b40f-bc2afb27e1bd                  
  ├─fedora_localhost--live-home ext4        1.0            6a99e0ff-a3f3-4a49-b9cb-dcabdc951784                  
  └─fedora_localhost--live-var  ext4        1.0            a20aa6a5-2b6e-47fc-aecd-c7e25a388113                  


The filtered tree for /boot on the Kali installation looks like this:
└─# tree -P *grub* -P *efi* /boot
/boot
├── efi
│   ├── EFI
│   │   ├── BOOT
│   │   │   ├── fbia32.efi
│   │   │   └── fbx64.efi
│   │   └── kali
│   │       └── grubx64.efi
│   └── System
│       └── Library
│           └── CoreServices
├── grub
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grubenv
│   ├── locale
│   ├── themes
│   │   └── kali
│   │       ├── grub-16x9.png
│   │       ├── grub-4x3.png
│   │       └── grub_background.sh
│   └── x86_64-efi
│       ├── core.efi
│       ├── efi_gop.mod
│       ├── efi_uga.mod
│       ├── efifwsetup.mod
│       ├── efinet.mod
│       ├── efitextmode.mod
│       ├── grub.efi
│       ├── lsefi.mod
│       ├── lsefimmap.mod
│       └── lsefisystab.mod
└── lost+found


I have read the following question Options for dual-booting 2+ Ubuntu-based distros/flavours installed on the same disk and it seems to be a similar situation, but my config seems to have a twist, because  gparted is showing that I have two EFI System Partitions (ESP).
One is on nvme0n1p1 (Kali), and the other is on nvme0n1p4 (Fedora).
Questions

Where did I go wrong?
What steps are required to enable one Linux distro in the grub menu of the other distro?


You have two of everything. Normally one ESP per drive as FAT32, but FAT16 was supposed to work on small external devices. And advantage of LVM over partitions is one large Volume over entire drive, or one physical partition is used. LVM has PVs (physical volumes), VGs (Volume Groups), and LVs (Logical Volumes). Then VG & LV inside that one. Can you copy boot stanza from Kali to Fedora's 40_custom or add a configfle entry to boot Kali's ESP grub? Kali not really intended for full install. It is a pen test distribution. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392441&p=13816046#post13816046

Thanks for the comment. What does the LVG configuration have to do with my issues? I'm not sure how I would go about creating a manual entry for Kali in the grub.cfg of Fedora. Could you please elaborate in an answer? What information would you require me to add to my question? I'm getting downvotes and no hints as to what I could do to improve the question.

Please excuse me, I missed the link in your comment on my first pass. Will digest the information and see if I can apply it to my situation.

Why are you installing both Kali & fedora? Any software in Kali is going to be available for Fedora, so in that respect, you gain nothing. You are not even gaining any kind of isolation. If you need isolation, then install Kali in a vm.

@BobGoddard Well, why not? I do realize that I could install everything that is available on Kali to Fedora or vice versa, but I like to keep things separated. Better that a VM would be possibly to use VeraCrypt and hide the partitions containing Kali. There are many options. I'm just trying to install two Linux distros to one drive with working entries in the GRUB menu.
